# Getting buid error in node.js for Android

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

i am getting build error after i add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in Androidmanifest.xml file, without `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` can build . In android ver 10 devices cant create directory so i added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`.
I am build with node.js cmd prompt. Error as follow

```
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.908 secs
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
F:\Mobile Projects\1652019\FingerTips\OAMobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:39: AAPT: No resource identifier found for attribute 'requestLegacyExternalStorage' in package 'android'

F:\Mobile Projects\1652019\FingerTips\OAMobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:39: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'requestLegacyExternalStorage' in package 'android'



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
```

What i tried, i remove android platform and add again, still getting error, i install this plugin also `cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.+`

when i trace with this command gradle compileDebug --scan , i get below 2 error

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'F:\Mobile Projects\1652019\FingerTips\OAMobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

- 

## Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> buildToolsVersion is not specified.

- 

## Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Regards and Thanks
Aravind

Answer (score 1):

> AAPT: No resource identifier found for attribute 'requestLegacyExternalStorage' in package 'android'

This is generally caused by using an incompatible build tools version. For `requestLegacyExternalStorage`, you need version 29.x build tools.

Open up Android Studio's SDK Manager and install the latest version of build tools available. Then make sure the build tools directory is in your `PATH` environment variable. Don't forget to restart your terminal session after changing your environment variables.

Comment: Thanks , Could u provide what build tools dir need to give in PATH environment variable, bcz Android build tools appear in 3 and more places in my system , like C:\Android,C:\windows\Android, C:\program files\android, C:\program files (x86)\android and also i cant add PATH variable, bcz getting error like string character is long 1024 .

Comment: That depends on your environment. Build tools directory will be located inside your `%ANDROID_HOME%/build-tools`. Inside this folder there will be a folder for each version you have installed. So your full path should be something like `%ANDROID_HOME%/build-tools/<version you want to use goes here>`. To be clear you shouldn't be replacing your `PATH` variable, just appending to it (or change the line for build tools if it already exists.)

Comment: Hi, i add build tool path ,even i got error,when i run "cordova requirements" i get following details
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-23,android-24,android-25,android-26,android-27,android-28,android-Q,android-29
Cannot read property 'version' of undefined  -- is anything i forgot ?